# lightbox open image on second touch

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ios, css

Is it possible open one image on second touch the screen?

I can not found documentation on-line!!

I have to do:

Fist touch show title, and for this I have write a few line of `js` where the title of the img is write inside the `a` tag and with hover of mouse show the content from img.

The second touch opens the image in Lightbox.

```
 $(".foto a").addClass("image");
    $("a.image").each(function(){
        $(this).attr('alt',$(this).find("img").attr('alt'));});

a.image {
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden
}

.image {
    position: relative
}

.image img {
    width: 100%;
    vertical-align: top
}

.image:after, .image:before {
    position: absolute;
    opacity: 0;
    transition: all 0.5s;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s;
}

.image:after {
    content: '\A';
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
}

.image:before {
    content: attr(alt);
    width: 100%;
    color: #fff;
    z-index: 1;
    bottom: 0;
    padding: 15px 20px;
    font-size: 16px;
    font-family: "futura-pt", sans-serif;
}

.image:hover:after, .image:hover:before {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

At moment this work well on the desktop, but in mobile no because of the Lightbox open on the first touch.
So I can found a solution for open the image on the second touch, in the way on the first is possible can see the hover effect?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok guys i have found this code that work so well!!!

[Link to the article](http://www.hnldesign.nl/work/code/mouseover-hover-on-touch-devices-using-jquery/)

```
$(".foto a").addClass("image").addClass("taphover");
$("a.image").each(function(){
    $(this).attr('alt',$(this).find("img").attr('alt'));
});

$('a.taphover').on('touchstart', function (e) {
'use strict'; //satisfy the code inspectors
var link = $(this); //preselect the link
if (link.hasClass('hover')) {
    return true;
} else {
    link.addClass('hover');
    $('a.taphover').not(this).removeClass('hover');
    e.preventDefault();
    return false; //extra, and to make sure the function has consistent return points
}
});
```

I don't have change my the css and work, but if you want do something with a new style use:

```
a.taphover:hover, a.taphover.hover {
    // css for hovering here
};
```